# Image within a div element doesn't handle the CSS active pseudo class

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox

I have an image, located within a div element, and this div element changes some of its style properties when the mouse passes over it, using the CSS :hover pseudo-class. This works fine in all browsers. But the div element also has another class, :active, which is supposed to change its background color when clicked.

Here is when things start to break. In IE9 (the version i have installed), when I click on the image, the background color of the div doesn't change. Only when I click elsewhere on the div, it works, the color changes. In Firefox, it doesn't matter where I click within the div element, the background color changes, even if I click on the image. This is how I want IE to behave too, so when the usem clicks on the div, no matter where inside it, the :active effect would be triggered.

Is there a workaround or something I can use to make it work for IE?

Comment: Need to see actual code. Maybe put up a demo at http://jsfiddle.net.

Comment: The description is quite clear... Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pcd9g/) reproducing the issue. Issue is there in IE8 too.

Comment: i thought :active psuedo-class can only be used with anchor tag

Answer (score 1):

After a bit of toying around with the css on the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pcd9g/), I didn't find any CSS way to solve this : IE just doesn't want to consider the **img** as a part of the **div**.

I'd suggest you to solve this in javascript. Using onMouseDown.

pseudo :

```
(div or img).onMouseDown(div.addClass:"active")
(div or img).onMouseUp(div.removeClass : "active").
```

I'd suggest using a js framework to make it easier. See [jquery mouseup](http://api.jquery.com/mouseup/) and [mousedown](http://api.jquery.com/mousedown/).

Comment: Thanks Kraz, i'll give it try. But I anticipate bad things ahead :) Fixing a problem in one technology with another technology seems a little scary to me. Like putting a nail on the wall with a shoe :) Pitty that IE9, with all its super hi-tech, still has quircks carried from older versions. But thanks anyways buddy :)

Comment: Look at this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pcd9g/3/). When you click on the image (click run if it doesn't appear), in IE, it becomes pink. In FF, it goes teal. When you click on an image in firefox, the div __and__ the image become active. In IE, __only__ the image become active. Since you can't select a parent node in CSS only, you gotta use JavaScript (or change your design, or abandon IE support).

Answer (score 0):

There's a trickier work around to this issue.

You can put up another div on top of the image as an overlay and make that div to respond to clicks and mouse actions and using jQuery add effects to the div underneath the image